# Spark / Mesos / Tasks lost, slaves blacklisted, executors removed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mesos, spark-submit

I am running a spark-submit job on Spark 2.2.0 with Scala 2.11.11, SBT on Mesos 1.4.2.

I have problem with tasks being lost and executors not being registered. Here are the symptoms:

MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend launches tasks until spark.cores.max is reached. For example here it launches 6 tasks:

```
18/06/11 12:49:54 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Received 2 resource offers.
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Accepting offer: a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-O585462 with attributes: Map() mem: 423417.0 cpu: 55.5 ports: List((1025,2180), (2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,5507), (5509,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8792), (8794,9177), (9179,12396), (12398,16297), (16299,16839), (16841,18310), (18312,21795), (21797,22269), (22271,32000)).  Launching 2 Mesos tasks.
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Launching Mesos task: 2 with mem: 11264.0 cpu: 20.0 ports: 
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Launching Mesos task: 0 with mem: 11264.0 cpu: 20.0 ports: 
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Accepting offer: a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-O585463 with attributes: Map() mem: 300665.0 cpu: 71.5 ports: List((1025,2180), (2182,2718), (2721,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,5455), (5457,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8262), (8264,8558), (8560,8792), (8794,10231), (10233,16506), (16508,18593), (18595,32000)).  Launching 3 Mesos tasks.
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Launching Mesos task: 4 with mem: 11264.0 cpu: 20.0 ports: 
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Launching Mesos task: 3 with mem: 11264.0 cpu: 20.0 ports: 
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Launching Mesos task: 1 with mem: 11264.0 cpu: 20.0 ports: 
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Received 2 resource offers.
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Accepting offer: a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-O585464 with attributes: Map() mem: 423417.0 cpu: 55.5 ports: List((1025,2180), (2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,5507), (5509,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8792), (8794,9177), (9179,12396), (12398,16297), (16299,16839), (16841,18310), (18312,21795), (21797,22269), (22271,32000)).  Launching 1 Mesos tasks.
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Launching Mesos task: 5 with mem: 11264.0 cpu: 20.0 ports: 
18/06/11 12:49:55 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Declining offer: a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-O585465 with attributes: Map() mem: 300665.0 cpu: 71.5 port: List((1025,2180), (2182,2718), (2721,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,5455), (5457,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8262), (8264,8558), (8560,8792), (8794,10231), (10233,16506), (16508,18593), (18595,32000)) for 120 seconds  (reason: reached spark.cores.max)
```

Then immediately afterwards it starts to lose tasks and blacklist slaves even thought I have set `spark.blacklist.enabled=false`

```
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 2 is now TASK_LOST
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 0 is now TASK_LOST
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-S0 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 4 is now TASK_LOST
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 3 is now TASK_LOST
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-S1 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 1 is now TASK_LOST
18/06/11 12:49:55 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-S1 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
```

Afterwards `non-existent` executors are removed

```
18/06/11 12:49:56 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Received 2 resource offers.
18/06/11 12:49:56 DEBUG CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove executor 2 with reason Executor finished with state LOST
18/06/11 12:49:56 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 2 requested
18/06/11 12:49:56 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Declining offer: a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-O585466 with attributes: Map() mem: 300665.0 cpu: 71.5 port: List((1025,2180), (2182,2718), (2721,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,5455), (5457,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8262), (8264,8558), (8560,8792), (8794,10231), (10233,16506), (16508,18593), (18595,32000)) 
18/06/11 12:49:56 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
18/06/11 12:49:56 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Declining offer: a6031461-f185-424d-940e-b45fb64a2aaf-O585467 with attributes: Map() mem: 412153.0 cpu: 35.5 port: List((1025,2180), (2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,5507), (5509,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8792), (8794,9177), (9179,12396), (12398,16297), (16299,16839), (16841,18310), (18312,21795), (21797,22269), (22271,32000)) 
18/06/11 12:49:56 DEBUG CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove executor 0 with reason Executor finished with state LOST
18/06/11 12:49:56 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 0 requested
18/06/11 12:49:56 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
18/06/11 12:49:56 DEBUG CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove executor 4 with reason Executor finished with state LOST
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 4 requested
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 4
18/06/11 12:49:59 DEBUG CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove executor 3 with reason Executor finished with state LOST
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 3 requested
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 3
18/06/11 12:49:59 DEBUG CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove executor 1 with reason Executor finished with state LOST
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 1 requested
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 5 is now TASK_RUNNING
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 4 from BlockManagerMaster.
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
```

Note however that one single task 5 was not lost and the executor 5 was not removed

```
18/06/11 12:49:59 INFO MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 5 is now TASK_RUNNING
18/06/11 12:50:01 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (SlaveIp:46884) with ID 5
18/06/11 12:50:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager SpaveIP:32840 with 5.2 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(5, SlaveIP, 32840, None)
```

Here is my SparkSession setup:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
.config("spark.executor.cores", 20)
.config("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", numPartitionsShuffle)
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.config("spark.network.timeout", "1200s")
.config("spark.blacklist.enabled", false)
.config("spark.blacklist.maxFailedTaskPerExecutor", 100)
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", false)
.getOrCreate()
```

And here is my spark-submit script

```
spark-submit \
  --class MyMainClass \
  --master mesos://masterIP:7077 \
  --total-executor-cores 120 \
  --driver-memory 200g \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --name MyMainClass \
  --conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false" \
  --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" \
  --conf "spark.blacklist.enabled=false" \
  --conf "spark.blacklist.maxFailedTaskPerExecutor=100" \
  --verbose \
  myJar-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Note:

- I noticed that if I make a break, and run the job it ofter runs well. But If I try to run jobs in quick succession or after I killed previous one, the problems as described above appear.
- I have enough resources on my cluster to run these tasks
- I am duplicating settings in SparkSession and spark-submit because it seems that precedence of `config` vs `--conf` is not always clear.
- It is important to run in non-dynamic mode.
- The executors that are lost are
- I compared the debug logs with those of our old still active retiring cluster installation based on Spark 2.0.1. There exactly the same code launches tasks which immediately get a `TASK_RUNNING` status.
- My google and StackOverflow searches did not yield any useful information.
- Setup of `spark.blacklist.maxFailedTaskPerExecutor` and `spark.blacklist.enabled` doesn't seem to work
- Related unanswered question [Spark on Mesos (DC/OS) loses tasks before doing anything
  ]([Spark on Mesos (DC/OS) loses tasks before doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561586/spark-on-mesos-dc-os-loses-tasks-before-doing-anything_)

I am completely lost here what is going on.

Questions:

1. Do you need any more info to help me diagnose this?
2. Why is the job loosing most of the tasks as soon as they are launched? I saw [Task Reasons](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/task-state-reasons/) but none of the reasons seems to explain it.
3. Why is it saying *Asked to remove non-existent executor*?
4. In which direction should I look at it?
5. Does it have something to do with previous job being killed and not waiting long enough to launch next one?

Comment: This is a nearly perfect StackOverflow question. Well done!

Comment: You say that running jobs in "quick succession" alters the outcome -- this suggests some kind of race condition: if so, google the error messages, as this would likely be a bug in the library itself (e.g. Spark).  I suspect the reason the other containers are being killed is that the system has detected a specific failure case, which might include possible race conditions seen as "non-responsive" processes.  "Non-existent executor" suggests that something one component expects -- a process, file, response, etc -- doesn't appear to be there.  Googling specific error messages is the way to go.

Comment: Here's a link I found on Google having the text of an interesting error message: "Asked to remove executor 2 with reason Executor finished with state LOST" and found this nice explanation of why this error may occur: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend-DriverEndpoint.html

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr thanks for the comments. Interestingly there are no error messages in my example because the job does not fail. It continues to run with the single executor. I just kill it before it finishes. I googled all the warning/debug messages but nothing useful came out of it. Blacklisted slaves and removed executors don't even show up as warnings. Log4j at WARN level does not indicate any of problems. The job simply has one executor without any info about that in StdErr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question:

We found that our problem is two fold.

1. Some unidentified problem of communication/connection between master and workers is causing loss of Mesos tasks (executors). There was nothing in the logs that explained what this problem is.
2. Each time at least 2 Mesos tasks are lost on a worker, it gets blacklisted. In Spark 2.2 the limit of 2 is hardcoded in the code and can't be changed. See this for details: [Blacklist is always active for MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/20640)

As a result:

- Sometimes communication problem didn't occur and job was executing normally.
- Most of the time all executors were lost right at the beginning of the job. By having 2 workers in our cluster we were able to run only 3 executors at once. At the beginning of the job all executors (2 on worker1 and 1 on worker2) would be lost but only worker1 would be blacklisted and the lost executors would be relaunched on worker2 and continue to run without problems.

**Solution:**

I am not sure if this is general solution to this problem but we somewhat blindly searched for configs that regulate different mesos `timeout` mechanisms and we found this bug in Mesos 1.4:

[Using a failoverTimeout of 0 with Mesos native scheduler client can result in infinite subscribe loop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-8171)

As a test we have set the `SparkSession` config `spark.mesos.driver.failoverTimeout=1.0`. This seemed to solve our problem. We don't loose our executors anymore at the beginning of the job.